# If value that is in a column on sheet A but doesn't exist in a column on sheet B add that value to sheet B

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a script that will look in a column A on sheet1 and see if it is missing any values from column J on sheet2, and if it is missing have the value added to the bottom of the column on sheet1. I found some example code (see below), however, when I modify it to work across the two sheets I get an error.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, MySel As Range, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

With ws
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngA = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    Set rngB = .Range("B1", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In rngB
    If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, rngA, 0)) Then
        If MySel Is Nothing Then
            Set MySel = cell
        Else
            Set MySel = Union(MySel, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If Not MySel Is Nothing Then MySel.Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
End Sub
```

Any help to modify this to function across sheets would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` but I don't see any other reference to another worksheet in your code. Where are you expecting the 2nd worksheet to be referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Array approach using one-liner for `Match()`**

Instead of looping through a data range you can execute an array `Match()`
to compare *data* values with **ref***erence* values by a *one-liner*:

```
data = Application.Match(ref, data, 0)
```

**Methodical hint**

Findings return the position within the reference array, whereas all non-findings (i.e. new and therefore unique values) can be identified easily by a corresponding error entry. This is used to re-write the data array exclusively by the wanted uniques. The resulting data are eventually added in the needed size to the existing data.

**Note** *that commonly the `Match()` function loops asking for* **single** *search values (1st parameter) within a reference array (2nd parameter),
e.g. via `Application.Match(SingleSearchValue, reference, 0)`.*

Side note: looping through a range by means of VBA can be time consuming for greater data set, so generally I prefer an array approach.

As OP seems to refer to two sheets with different columns `A` and `J` (instead of `B`),
I demonstrate a solution following this requirement.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AppendNewItems()
'1) get data & reference arrays via function GetDatafield()
    Dim data: data = GetDatafield(Sheet1, "A")  ' current data 
    Dim ref:  ref = GetDatafield(Sheet2, "J")   ' reference values
    Dim NewRow As Long
    NewRow = UBound(data) + 1           ' get starting row for new entries
    
'2) look up all of the data in the reference array and write found positions to data (one-liner)
    data = Application.Match(ref, data, 0)

    'Edit2: check for no or only 1 reference item ' << 2021-07-23/see comment
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print data(1, 1)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        ReDim tmp(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        tmp(1, 1) = data(1)
        data = tmp
    End If
    
'3) take only new (=unique) elements
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)           ' loop through matches
        If IsError(data(i, 1)) Then     ' identify new (=not found) elements by error
            ii = ii + 1                 ' increment uniques counter
            data(ii, 1) = ref(i, 1)     ' replace error element with current reference value
        End If
    Next
'4) add new data to column A (not more than ii elements)
    If ii Then
        Sheet1.Range("A" & NewRow).Resize(ii, 1) = data
    End If

End Sub
```

**Help function `GetDatafield()`**

```
Function GetDatafield(sht As Worksheet, Col As String)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = sht.Range(Col & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'return 1-based 2-dim datafield array
    GetDatafield = sht.Range(Col & "1:" & Col & LastRow).Value2

    'force single value into array          ' << Edit 2021-07-22/see comment
    If Not IsArray(GetDatafield) Then       ' or: If LastRow = 1 Then
        ReDim tmp(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        tmp(1, 1) = sht.Range(Col & "1").Value2
        GetDatafield = tmp                  ' pass 2-dim array
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: When I run the macro I receive a compile error: Variable not defined for sheet1. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Sheet1` is just a suggestion for your project's  sheet (Code)Name; change it to your actual worksheet (Code)Name or use the current Excel tabular sheet name (which needn't be the same wording),  e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyTabularWorksheet")` :-) @endermanframework

Comment: I'm receiving a Type Mismatch error on the following line: NewRow = UBound(Data) + 1        ' get starting row for new entries

Comment: @endermanframework Edited help function; does this solve your issue?

Comment: That fixed the Type Mismatch error. Thanks! However, now I an getting a Application-defined or object-defined error on the following line "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TRK").Range("A" & NewRow).Resize(ii, 1) = data". I've confirmed that I have the correct sheet name and even attempted to reference the sheet using its location and I still received the error.

Comment: @endermanframework Provided for exception of no or only one reference item; see *Edit2* under section 2) in proc `AppendNewItems()`

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following code modification, you are getting the error due to the variable `cell` was not declared and `ws.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` is not a valid range, and you should set `Range B` by referring to another worksheet if you want to do so:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, MySel As Range
Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowB As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

With ws
    LastRowA = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowB = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngA = .Range("A1:A" & LastRowA)
    Set rngB = .Range("B1:B" & LastRowB)
End With

For Each cell In rngB.Cells

    If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, rngA, 0)) Then
        If MySel Is Nothing Then
            Set MySel = cell
        Else
            Set MySel = Union(MySel, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell


If Not MySel Is Nothing Then MySel.Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A" & LastRowA + 1)
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: The issue that I have with what you provided above is when I run the macro it replaces everything in range A with what is in range B. What I am trying to do is to add the values from range B to range A while avoiding duplicates.

Comment: You can see my full code using your code and the output result, it won't have duplicate value problem in my case. Do you set the workbook name correctly?